# Load webapp from NSHomeDirectory in Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova

I am working on `Cordova` `iOS-only` app where many files will be able to change over time. For example, the the HTML pages can be modified, new ones introduced, CSS, javascript files created or updated, ... 
Since the www folder is part of the app and can't be modified I am thinking of copying the whole www folder to the `NSHomeDirectory` folder (App Container directory) and let `Cordova` launch the webapp from that location. At some point the app will request the resources changed/created from a back-end and replace/create them in the `NSHomeDirectory`.

I can't find any info on anyone who had done this before but it is my understanding that it should work, shouldn't it? I foresee quite a number of changes on the CDVViewController, MainViewController and some others in order to load the resources from the appropriate location.

Does anyone foresee a problem with this approach?